# In Node, how do I request JSON from multiple URLs using promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, bluebird

Please forgive the fairly case-specific question, though I think the general end goal could be of use to other people.

**Goal: Populate a MongoDB with data requested from multiple JSON API URLs.**

Short question: So far I've had some success with [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise), which uses Bluebird:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var options = {
    uri: 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b006qsq5.json',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
    },
    json: true
};

rp(options)
    .then(function (body) {
        // Mongoose allows us query db for existing PID and upsert
        var query = {pid: body.programme.pid},
            update = {
                name: body.programme.title,
                pid: body.programme.pid,
                desc: body.programme.short_synopsis
            },
            options = { upsert: true, new: true };

        // Find the document
        Programme.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, result) {
            if (err) return res.send(500, { error: err });
            return res.send("succesfully saved");
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        return res.send(err);
    })
```

But how do I loop over an array of URLs, without the program failing if any of the promises are rejected?
Something like this for example, using Bluebird, fails if any of the URLs errors.

```
const urls = ['http://google.be', 'http://google.uk']

Promise.map(urls, rp)
  .map((htmlOnePage, index) => {
    return htmlOnePage;
  })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch((e) => console.log('We encountered an error' + e));
```

As I want to write to the DB with successful requests, and ignore those that might not be responding right then, I need something that skips over rejected promises, which `.all` does not do.

Long question:
I've been reading up about promises all day and it's making my head hurt! But I've found some good resources, such as https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html, which mentions the use of a Promise factory. Would this work for my case? I initially thought I should make each request, process the result and add it to the DB, then move on to the next request; but having seen `.all` I thought I should do all the requests, save the results in an array and loop over that with my DB saving function.

Should I even be using Promises for this? Maybe I should just make use of something like async.js and run my requests in series.

Thanks very much for any help or ideas.

Comment: If the requests are not dependent on each other no reason you need all() to do db updates

Comment: i think you can use async.eachSeries with promise. loop wont stop even if error occurs
http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachOfSeries

Comment: @AsifSaeed mixing Promises with async.js is not recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how do I loop over an array of URLs, without the program failing if any of the promises are rejected?

if you return a value from .catch other than a rejected promise, you will return a resolved promise

So, your .then for each individual request could return an object like

```
{
    success: true,
    result: whateverTheResultIs
}
```

and your catch returns

```
{
    success: false,
    error: whateverTheErrorIs
}
```

Really you don't NEED the success property, it's a convenience though

So the code would be - assuming `process(url)` returns a Promise

```
Promise.map(urls, url => 
    process(url)
    .then(result => ({result, success:true}))
    .catch(error => ({error, success:false}))
)
.then(results => {
    let succeeded = results.filter(result => result.success).map(result => result.result);
    let failed = results.filter(result => !result.success).map(result => result.error);
});
```

Or, in ES5

```
Promise.map(urls, function (url) {
    return process(url).then(function (result) {
        return { result: result, success: true };
    }).catch(function (error) {
        return { error: error, success: false };
    });
}).then(function (results) {
    var succeeded = results.filter(function (result) {
        return result.success;
    }).map(function (result) {
        return result.result;
    });
    var failed = results.filter(function (result) {
        return !result.success;
    }).map(function (result) {
        return result.error;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this very comprehensive explanation! The code reads well and makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is less about the bluebird api than structuring your promise chain.

```
const reducePropsToRequests = (props) => Promise.resolve(Object
  .keys(props)
  .reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = request(sources[key]);
    return acc;
  }, {}));

const hashToCollection = (hash) => Promise.resolve(Object
  .keys(hash)
  .reduce((acc, k) => {
    return [...acc, {source: k, data: hash[k]}];
  }, []));

const fetchFromSources = (sources) => Promise.props(sources);

const findSeveralAndUpdate = (results) => Promise
  .each(results.map(obj => {
    // you have access to original {a: 'site.com'}
    // here, so use that 'a' prop to your advantage by abstracting out
    // your db config somewhere outside your service
    return Programme.findOneAndUpdate(someConfig[obj.source], obj.data);
  }))

const requestFromSeveralAndUpdate = (sources) => reducePropsToRequests(sources)
  .then(fetchFromSources)
  .then(hashToCollection)
  .then(findSeveralAndUpdate)
  .catch(/* some err handler */);

requestFromSeveralAndUpdate({ a: 'site.com', b: 'site.net' });
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this answer, a better structure is just what I'm looking for. I'm just having some trouble getting all of it.. I got an error on `request(sources[key])`, should that be `props[key]`? Also it doesn't seem to handle an erroneous request (eg 404) and I can't quite see where I would handle that. thnx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this fit your case, but I think You can use a counter to check when all promises has returned, regardless of the fact that each one has been resolved or rejected

```js
var heroes = [
  'Superman',
  'Batman',
  'Spiderman',
  'Capitan America',
  'Ironman',
];

function getHero(hero) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return Math.round(Math.random()) ? resolve(hero + ' lives') : reject(hero + ' dead');
    }, Math.random() * 3000)    
  })
}

function checkHeroes() {
  var checked = heroes.length;
  heroes.forEach((hero) => {
    getHero(hero)
    .then((res) => {
      checked --;
      console.log(res);
      if (!checked) done();   
    })
    .catch((err) => { 
      checked --;
      console.log(err);
      if (!checked) done();      
    });           
  }) 
}

function done() {
  console.log('All heroes checked');
}

checkHeroes();
```

Comment: One of the points of using promises is that you can use tools like `Promise.all()` with multiple promises rather than designing counters yourself to rebuild that functionality that already exists.  One might use counters like this when you don't have promises, but really should not be done when you do have promises.  In addition, since this is Bluebird promises, there are tools like `Promise.map()` that will iterate a collection for you and return a single promise that tracks all results.

Comment: I just stick to the standard Promises implementation.

Comment: `Promise.all()` is the standard promises implementation.  But, the question is specially tagged with Bluebird and using Bluebird so the best answer would take advantage of that where it simplifies things.

Answer (score -1):

I'd just use request and write my own promise with try catch inside that only resolves. Pseudo example below

```
var request = require('request')

var urls = ['http://sample1.com/json', 'http://sample2.com/json']

var processUrl = (url) => { 
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
     var result;
     try {
        var myRequest = {
           uri: url,
           method: 'GET',
           header: {...}
        };
        request(option, (res,body,err)=> {
            if(err) {
               result = err;
               return;
            }
            result = body;
        })
     }
     catch(e) {
         result = e;
     }
     finally {
        resolve(result)
     }
  })
}
```